# Novel about a man forbidden to do magic. Shares his magic with companions. Mother is a mage

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

This novel is about a man that has 'spirit magic' or some kind but the magic is illegal in the land because some prophet said so.

He gets companions with his magic and they share powers somewhat. I remember a troll/orc(?) as one of his friends that gives him strength, then the companion gets magic.

He has more than one companion in story.

I remember his mother is a mage and she teaches his orc/troll companion at one point in series.

Comment: Do you know when you read it? Possible date of publication? Maybe even a publisher?

Comment: Just as a reminder, you can accept Valorum's answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the books in the [The Bowl of Souls](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15752127-eye-of-the-moonrat) series, presumably [Mother of the Moonrat](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18584576-mother-of-the-moonrat). A cursory glance at the reviews show orcs, mages, a prophet who's forbidden magic in the kingdom, 'spirit magic' and a mother who's a mage.

> *The prophet had forbidden the teaching of spirit magic long ago and
>   yet this witch was skilled. And powerful. As powerful as any witch
>   that had existed during Mellinda's walking days. How had this woman become so good without being known?*

[image]

Comment: Yes this is it thank you

Comment: @Joshua - Don't forget to upvote and click the "accepted" button